# Using tables in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm developing a simple small game and I'm having some issues with addressing the data that I store in tables.

I'm quite a beginner so sorry in advance for the basic questions.

for example, (and yes, its a game with tampons..)

I created this table:

```
tampon={}
tampon.x=50
tampon.y=112
tampon.spr=6
```

and im saving the "tampon" into:

```
tampon_box={}
```

with this code:

```
add(tampon_box, tampon)
```

How can i print, or get the value of tampon.x that is stored inside the tampon_box?

Comment: What is `add`?  `tampon` should be inserted: `table.insert(tampon_box, tampon)`

Comment: Im not really sure why, maybe its the syntax in pico-8 program..?

using this as my "cheatsheet":

https://neko250.github.io/pico8-api/

Comment: You can give an id to the `tampon` if you will have multiple of them and add to `tampon_box` as `tampon_box[len+1]=tampon` and then do a for loop on tampon_box and check the id.